# Javascript - if/and/else not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

First off ... I'm fairly new to javascript ...

Here's the code I'm currently using, however it doesn't seem to be working properly.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish ...

If something has the 'typeset' value of "Complete set" and it's 'main' value is anything but "A2 tandem", then it's title variable should be "Line Set w/ ALinks: ".  If it has any other 'typeset' value or it's 'main' value is "A2 tandem", then it's title variable should be "Line Set: "

What's currently happening:
It doesn't seem to be differentiating between 'main' value being "A2 tandem".  It is still applying the "w/ ALinks: " title if the 'main' value is "A2 tandem".

Help?

```
    if (accCat == "Line Sets"){
        document.getElementById('o1').value = document.getElementById('main').value;
        document.getElementById('o2').value = document.getElementById('mainsize').value;
        document.getElementById('o3').value = document.getElementById('typeset').value;
        document.getElementById('o4').value = document.getElementById('typeline').value;

        var canopyValue = document.getElementById('main').value;
        var title;

        if ((document.getElementById('typeset').value == "Complete set") && (canopyValue != "A2 tandem")){
            title = "Line Set w/ ALinks: ";
        }else{
            title = "Line Set: ";
        }
```

Comment: What are the current results?

Comment: And always use === instead of ==.

Comment: Except for the missing closing bracket, you're not doing anything wrong. What exactly is not working properly?

Comment: I guess I should have said what was currently happening ... 

Typeset value = "Complete set" is setting the title to "Line Set w/ ALinks: "
Typeset value != "Complete set" is setting the title to "Line Set: "

What isn't working is if main value = A2 tandem.  If 'main' value is A2 tandem and 'typeset' value is "Complete set", it is setting the title to "Line Set w/ ALinks: ".  If 'main' value is A2 tandem and 'typeset' value is not "Complete set", it is setting the title to "Line Set: ".  So it seems to me as though it isn't checking the main value at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (accCat == "Line Sets"){ //<-------- YOU DIDN'T CLOSE THIS
    document.getElementById('o1').value = document.getElementById('main').value;
    document.getElementById('o2').value = document.getElementById('mainsize').value;
    document.getElementById('o3').value = document.getElementById('typeset').value;
    document.getElementById('o4').value = document.getElementById('typeline').value;

    var canopyValue = document.getElementById('main').value;
    var title;

    if ((document.getElementById('typeset').value == "Complete set") && (canopyValue != "A2 tandem")){
        title = "Line Set w/ ALinks: ";
    }else{
        title = "Line Set: ";
    }
```

Add a `}` to the end of the code.

Also a quick tip:

Instead of typing `document.getElementById("someId").value` every single time, just make a function that will get the element.

```
var get = function(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Then you can just access it like `get("o1").value = get("main").value`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've recently inherited this site and the guy that coded it originally clearly didn't opt for the path of least resistance, so I'm going through and trying to address the many bugs that exist - this is one that I figured I had pegged ... but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing brackets on your first `if`. You opened it, but the closing bracket doesn't come until after your `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the opening bracket of the initial if.
Anyway as you are new to Javascript consider that Javascript has 2 operators for EQUALS. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Given that x = 5

== equal value

x == 8 gives false
x == 5 gives true

===     equal value and equal type

x === "5"   false
x === 5     true

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the original `if`. Add a `}` to the end.